# php/mysql : Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database named "project_beta" which contains the following tables: offre, categorieOffre and fournisseur.

```
-fournisseur (idFournisseur, nomFournisseur)
-offre (idOffre, nomOffre, #idFournisseur, #idCatOffre)
-categorie_offre (idCatOffre, nomCatOffre, #idOffre);
```

When I do

```sql
INSERT INTO offre VALUES ('','".$nomOffre."','".$idFournisseur."','"idCatOffre"')
```

it displays this error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`project_beta`.`offre`, CONSTRAINT `offre_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`idCatOffre`) REFERENCES `categorie_offre` (`idCatOffre`)).

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you possibly missing a `$` on `$idCatOffre`?

Comment: Or idcatoffre is not in the category table.

Comment: You do btw have a problem with foreign keys. remove the foreign key in the category table pointing to offre table (idoffre)

Comment: the $ i just missed it here :).

Comment: the table categorie is not empty and contains more than 5 elements, so i would like to know if there a possibility to do an update or set the #idCatOffre manually because in phpmyadmin i have done it and i had the possibility to choose amongs the idOffre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several strange things.

- You are inserting an empty value in the idOffre field. That's a mighty strange value for an id. Normally I would expect this id to be automatically generated by the database and you shouldn't insert anything there.
- for the fourth field you leave text mode but don't use concatenation.
- I would advise agains starting the name of variables with #. Further on you're not using that character anymore.
- Inside double quotes php replaces variables so you don't have to concatenate
- I would expect #idFournisseur and #idCatOffre to be numbers too, so their value shouldn't be single quoted in your insert statement.

Also make sure that whatever value you use for #idFournisseur and #idCatOffre those values should preexist in the related tables.

Just a wild guess... shouldn't you do something like this

```
$query = "insert into offre(nomOffre, idFournisseur, idCatOffre) values ($nomOffre,$idFournisseur,$idCatOffre)";
```

Comment: To be clear the $nomOffre i get it from a formular. i done as what you showed but i got : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 1

Comment: Typo on my side: the single quotes around $nomOffre shouldn't have been there. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I got the solution, i have done an update sql request after the insert sql request. Thank's for every one.

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key constraint is there to make sure data integrity is preserved. If this constraint fails it's because you're trying to use a category id that is not contained in the categorie_offre table.